# Configure repo for SBT launcher in Travis build

Tags: scala, sbt, travis-ci

Where can I override the repo URL that SBT uses to fetch its launcher when the SBT instance is provided by Travis-CI?

http://typesafe.artifactoryonline.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt-launch/0.13.8/sbt-launch.jar is currently giving 404s and, as a result, the builds are failing on Travis with:

```
$ sbt clean dependencyUpdates coverage test coverageReport
Detected sbt version 0.13.8
Downloading sbt launcher for 0.13.8:
  From  http://typesafe.artifactoryonline.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt-launch/0.13.8/sbt-launch.jar
    To  /home/travis/.sbt/launchers/0.13.8/sbt-launch.jar
Download failed. Obtain the jar manually and place it at /home/travis/.sbt/launchers/0.13.8/sbt-launch.jar
```

Comment: I know it is too late, but you might have cached that, just like [spray does](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/.travis.yml).

Comment: We cache a subset of that. I'm guessing the wrong subset. It's the .m2 that's needed, I suppose...?  We have     - $HOME/.ivy2/cache
    - $HOME/.sbt/boot/

Comment: Based on the error message, you might need to add `$HOME/.sbt/launchers/` too.

Comment: Ah yes, of course. Cheers Gábor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ran into the same problem today, and logged an issue for travis-ci: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/4527

As a workaround, you can download the sbt-launcher.jar by adding a before_script section to your .travis.yml

```
before_script:
- mkdir -p $HOME/.sbt/launchers/0.13.8/
- curl -L -o $HOME/.sbt/launchers/0.13.8/sbt-launch.jar http://dl.bintray.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/sbt-launch/0.13.8/sbt-launch.jar
```

Comment: Great! I ran into this problem using Shippable, and the exact same fix works for shippable.yml

Answer (score 1):

We just deployed the fix to production. SBT builds should be working now.

Sorry for the inconvenience.

https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/4527#issuecomment-124123880

Comment: happening again today